# Use find with data attribute

Tags: jquery

I need to find the value of **data-extra-key** when click the **Remove** button.How can I do that ?

```
<tr class="<%: classNames %>">
            <td data-extra-key="<%: item.ServiceKey %>">
                <%: item.ServiceName %>
                for
                <%: item.PetName %><sub><%: item.Description %></sub>
            </td>

            <td>
                <%if (item.IsAnExtra && !item.IsCancelled)
                  { %>
                <button class="btnRemoveExtraService actionButton secondaryButton short" type="button" itemid="<%:item.Id%>">
                    Remove</button>
                <%} %>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I have tried like below (I don't know how to use **find** with **data attribute**) :

```
 $('.btnRemoveExtraService').die('click').live('click', function () {

                   var service= $(this).parents('tr').find('').val();

                     return false;

                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dataExtraKey = $(this)
                      .closest('tr')      //find the wrapping <tr>
                      .find('td:first')   //traverse down and get the first <td>
                      .data('extra-key'); //get the value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var service= $(this).parents('tr').find('[data-extra-key]').data('extra-key');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use like this

```
            $('.btnRemoveExtraService').die('click').live('click', function () {

               var service= $(this).parent().parent().find('td:first-child').data('extra-key');

                 return false;

            });
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

used this code :

```
$('.btnRemoveExtraService').click(function () {
   var service= $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').data('extra-key');
   return false;
});
```